# Show the latest item firest in Firebase ui Realtime database

Tags: java, firebase, android-recyclerview

I use firebase ui realtime database to show data in viewpager2 with RecyclerView adapter and i need to show the latest item firest how can i do that ?

And you can find sample code of that in here
[Here simple code of my project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72184951/19074762)

Comment: Have you tried something so far in code?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes this is my code https://stackoverflow.com/q/72184951/19074762